# Save data in 2 different tables with laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

how can i save a record in 2 different tables.
I have my article model and my article controller in this way. My second table is called History
I hope you can help me, thank you very much

my article model:

```
 protected $fillable =[
        'idcategoria','codigo','nombre','precio_proveedor','precio_venta','iva','ieps','stock','stock1','descripcion','condicion'
    ];
    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria');
    }
```

my article controller, store method:

```
 protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    // this triggers everytime an Article model is saved
    static::saved(dd($articulo) { dd($article);
        $historial = new Historial();
        $historial->nombre = $articulo->nombre;
        $historial->precio_proveedor = $articulo->precio_proveedor;
        $historial->stock = $articulo->stock;
        $historial->save();
    });
}
```

In my history table I only need to save nombre, precio_proveedor,
stock

Comment: do you need to put data in History table everytime you save the article model?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to duplicate the record but only nombre,precio_proveedor and stock

Comment: you can use observers for this. Whenever article is saved you update or create the history model. I'll post an answer

Comment: ready then is the model ok?

Comment: `dd($articulo)` like this `static::saved(function (Article $article) {
            dd($article); $history = new History();
            $history->nombre = $article->nombre;
            $history->precio_proveedor = $article->precio_proveedor;
            $history->stock = $article->stock;
            $history->save();
        });`

Comment: does not save, already modify the model

Comment: apparently the browser console sends me an error about the url
article / register

Comment: any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use observers for this. Add this in your `Article` model:

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        // this triggers everytime an Article model is saved
        static::saved(function (Article $article) {
            $history = new History();
            $history->nombre = $article->nombre;
            $history->precio_proveedor = $article->precio_proveedor;
            $history->stock = $article->stock;
            $history->save();
        });
    }
```

Reference: https://www.larashout.com/how-to-use-laravel-model-observers

Comment: doesn't save me anything :(

Comment: add the Article model in your question so I can check

Comment: delete the answer and edit your original question and put it there. also `dd($articulo)` in `static::saved()` to check if you get the model